# Warp with Mongo DB Global Resource Injection

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-warp

I have set up a database connection but I want to share it with my warp API handlers.

my Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "mongo-warp"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
dotenv = "0.15.0"
mongodb = "2.2.2"
bson = { version = "2", features = ["chrono-0_4"] } 
tokio = "1"
serde = "1" 
warp = "0.3"
serde_json = "1.0"
```

and in main I have the database setup and working along with the routes that I'm importing from auth.rs

```
mod auth;

use dotenv;
use tokio;
use std::{env, error::Error};
use mongodb::{options::{ClientOptions}, Client, bson::doc};
use warp::Filter;

use crate::auth::auth_filter;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    dotenv::dotenv().ok();
    let client_uri = env::var("MONGODB_URI").expect("You must set the MONGODB_URI .env");
    let options = ClientOptions::parse(&client_uri).await?;
    let client = Client::with_options(options)?;

    // TODO: Do this bit in the join_handler
    let users = client.database("rusty_db").collection("users");
    let user = doc! { "password": "1984", "username": "GeorgeOrwell" };
    let insert_result = users.insert_one(user, None).await?;
    println!("New document ID: {}", insert_result.inserted_id);
    // End

    let apis = auth_filter();
    let welcome = warp::path::end().map(|| "Welcome to my api");

    let routes = apis.or(welcome);
    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000)).await;

    Ok(())
}
```

and finally, the route which is where I want to have access to the database with join_handler and signin_handler

```
use serde_json::{json, Value};
use warp::{Filter, reply::Json};

pub fn auth_filter() -> impl Filter<Extract = impl warp::Reply, Error = warp::Rejection> + Clone {
    let join = warp::path("join")
    .and(warp::get())
    .and(warp::path::end())
    .and_then(join_handler);

    let signin = warp::path("signin")
    .and(warp::post())
    .and(warp::body::json())
    .and_then(signin_handler);

    join.or(signin)
}

async fn join_handler() -> Result<Json, warp::Rejection> {
    let user = json!({"username":"GeorgeOrwell", "password": "1984", "id": "62a5108336aaebf431faa522"});
    let user = warp::reply::json(&user);
    Ok(user)
}

async fn signin_handler(data: Value) -> Result<Json, warp::Rejection> {
    let credentials = data;
    let credentials = warp::reply::json(&credentials);
    Ok(credentials)
}
```

Comment: Never really used warp, but look into how to add data into routes via filters. This article has an example called `with_db` that probably does what you need.

Comment: If you are just trying to share `Database` between handlers, you can make it a static, since [the docs specify](https://docs.rs/mongodb/2.2.2/mongodb/struct.Database.html) "`Database` uses `std::sync::Arc` internally, so it can safely be shared across threads or async tasks". It is hard to understand what exactly your problem is, though.

Comment: inside `join_handler()` and `signin_handler()` i want to be able to  insert an item into the database, and I can't figure out how I can share the database connection I made in `main()`

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test this without setting up a new database and everything, but if you move your `Database` client out to a `lazy_static`, then you can import it into your `auth` module and use it as if it were a local variable:

```rust
use dotenv;
use tokio;
use std::{env, error::Error};
use mongodb::{options::ClientOptions, Client, bson::doc};
use warp::Filter;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

use crate::auth::auth_filter;

lazy_static! {
    static ref MONGO_DB: mongodb::Database = {
        tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap().block_on(async {
            Client::with_options(
                ClientOptions::parse(
                    env::var("MONGODB_URI").expect("You must set the MONGODB_URI .env")
                )
                .await
                .unwrap()
            )
            .unwrap()
            .database("rusty_db")
        })
    };
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    dotenv::dotenv().ok();

    let apis = auth_filter();
    let welcome = warp::path::end().map(|| "Welcome to my api");

    let routes = apis.or(welcome);
    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000)).await;

    Ok(())
}

mod auth {
    use mongodb::bson::doc;
    use serde_json::{json, Value};
    use warp::{Filter, reply::Json};
    use crate::MONGO_DB;

    pub fn auth_filter() -> impl Filter<Extract = impl warp::Reply, Error = warp::Rejection> + Clone {
        let join = warp::path("join")
        .and(warp::get())
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and_then(join_handler);

        let signin = warp::path("signin")
        .and(warp::post())
        .and(warp::body::json())
        .and_then(signin_handler);

        join.or(signin)
    }

    async fn join_handler() -> Result<Json, warp::Rejection> {
        let users = MONGO_DB.collection("users");
        let user = doc! { "password": "1984", "username": "GeorgeOrwell" };
        let insert_result = users.insert_one(user, None).await.unwrap();
        println!("New document ID: {}", insert_result.inserted_id);

        let user = json!({"username":"GeorgeOrwell", "password": "1984", "id": "62a5108336aaebf431faa522"});
        let user = warp::reply::json(&user);
        Ok(user)
    }

    async fn signin_handler(data: Value) -> Result<Json, warp::Rejection> {
        let credentials = data;
        let credentials = warp::reply::json(&credentials);
        Ok(credentials)
    }
}
```

This way, the database connection is still in your `main.rs`, but it is not in `main` itself, which I think is the only part that you were missing when trying to use it in other modules. (I moved your `auth` module into the same file for testing, but you should be able to put it wherever you had it)